# How can I definine a class inside a function, then access it from outside said function in Python?

Tags: python, class

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def genclass():
  class stuff:
    foo = 'Foo'
    bar = 'Bar'

genclass()
```

How would I access that class outside of the function? I tried the following:

- Just print the function:

`print(stuff.foo)`

- Print it with the function name:

`print(genclass.stuff.foo)`

- Same, but with () to indicate that genclass is a function:

`print(genclass().stuff.foo)`

Unfortunately, none of the above worked.

Comment: Classes are objects just like anything else. If you want to pass a class out from a function, just ``return`` it. However, that is the naive solution – usually, one does not *have* to return a class in the first place, because it is not defined inside the function. Why do want to define the class inside the function?

Comment: Why would you extract something from the closure?

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can store the class objects in a list and return the list, but you can only access the classes by index.

```
def genclass():
    class stuff:
        foo = 'foo'
        bar = 'bar'
    class other:
        one = 'one'
        two = 'two'
    return [stuff, other]
```

> >>> genclass()[0].foo
> 'foo'
> >>> genclass()[1].one
> 'one'

But this is basically treating the function as a list.
edit::
You can also use it as both a function that executes another command if you include an if-statement to check if a parameter is passed.

```
def genclass(arg = None):
    class stuff:
        foo = 'foo'
        bar = 'bar'
    if arg:
        print('parameter passed')
    else:
        return [stuff]
```

> >>> genclass()[0].bar
> 'bar'
> >>> genclass(1)
> parameter passed

Comment: Why the list *of two* classes? Why not return the *single* class shown in the question?

Comment: I did it for demonstration. I just assumed the question asks to access specific objects from specific classes inside the function, so I included another and put them inside a list so they can be accessed by index.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is setting an attribute in a function. You can't do it directly, but you need to call the setattr function.

You can do something like:

```py
def genclass():
    class stuff:
        foo = 'Foo'
        bar = 'Bar'
    setattr(genclass, 'stuff', stuff)
```

And then, after executing the function, because everything inside a function is ran just after its execution, you can access the class by typing

```py
genclass.stuff
```

Anyway, this is a workaround and I don't think it is a best practice.

For better understand what a function is in Python and why you can set them an attribute please have a look on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Python-function-attributes

Comment: Notwithstanding that "setting an attribute" is not exactly ideal, there is no need for ``setattr``. It is perfectly possible to set the attribute directly as ``genclass.stuff = stuff``.

Comment: Yeah, mine was just an approach. Maybe my sentence was not correctly, I meant that you need to explicitly set the attribute to the function, that is different from setting an attribute class (defining it in the class definition), that I thought was what SkyyySi was trying do do.